# Can I apply PHP's open_basedir to socket paths?

Tags: php, open-basedir, unix-socket

The PHP manual states:

> *open_basedir (string)*
>
> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
>
> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to access it.

Also, a little bit further...

> **open_basedir can affect more than just filesystem functions**; for example if MySQL is configured to use mysqlnd drivers, LOAD DATA INFILE will be affected by open_basedir . Much of the extended functionality of PHP uses open_basedir in this way.

However, it seems that this restriction does not reach socket manipulation. On my server, even though I have set `open_basedir` to `/home:/tmp`, I can still access a socket file under `/run` through the `socket_connect` function (note that I haven't moved `/var/run` (`/run`) to some twisted location under `/home` or `/tmp`).

Is there a way to extend `open_basedir`'s restrictions to include socket files* paths, so that it is impossible to open a socket file outside of `/home` and `/tmp`?

<sub>* I understand that socket files are not really "opened", but rather "bound to" through the `socket_connect` function and the `bind` system call. However, since `open_basedir` seems to apply on non-filesystem functions... I'm guessing there could be a way.</sub>

Comment: I'd love to know why my question has been migrated, since it appears to be about the setup of a PHP-enabled web server... I may be wrong though.